# How to programically change the function name I call

Tags: c#, function, combobox

I am trying to call a function based on information from a combobox. The user will change the combobox and in doing so we call a function according to the data in the combobox text joined with a fixed text. I am trying to do this so every time we get a new version I just add a folder and do not have to go into the code to add new function names like in a case statement.

The combobox would have text as

```
v6.1
v6.4 
v7.2
v8.6
```

and so on

The function I want to call is named Getinfo_ with the addition of the text from the combobox with the . replaced with _ e.g. I would choose v6.1 from combobox and in doing so I would call function called Getinfo_v6_1

After a lot of thinking searching and trying I have got close but not close enough yet. I think I need to use Reflection (maybe not) and

```
private void cmbobx_version_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Type t = this.GetType(); //need to get the type
    MethodInfo method = t.GetMethod("Getinfo" + cmbobx_version.Text.Replace('.', '_'));   //put together function name
     method.Invoke(this, new object[] {Fridge, "Order" }); //call function with parameters
}
```

Unfortunately this stops at invoke saying the method is NULL, I do not understand why this is so apart from maybe I totally misunderstand what I am doing.

The function I want to call would look a bit like the following

```
public void Getinfo_v6_1(ComboBox inFocusComboBox, string action)
{
  switch (inFocusComboBox.Text)
        {
           case "Red": Price = 11254; break;
           case "Blue": Price = 11278; break;
           case "Green": Price = 11354; break;
         }
}


public void Getinfo_v6_4(ComboBox inFocusComboBox, string action)
{
   switch (inFocusComboBox.Text)
        {
            case "Red": Price = 254; break;
            case "Blue": Price = 278; break;
            case "Green": Price = 354; break;
          }
}
```

All help greatly appreciated even if you have a better way of doing what I need to do.

Comment: Seems like a possible [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) to me. I could be wrong, though.

Comment: You said you are trying to call functions named `Getinfo_v6_1` for example but the code you build the string with `"Getinfo" + cmbobx_version.Text.Replace('.', '_'));` will give you names `Getinfov6_1` without the underscore after `info`. You could see this if you moved the string into its own variable and inspect it in the debugger. `string fnName = "Getinfo" + cmbobx_version.Text.Replace('.', '_'));` It should be `"Getinfo_" + cmbobx_version.Text.Replace('.', '_'));`

Comment: It's because you're missing an underscore after `Getinfo` when you search for the method name. Voting to close because "typo".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Ĵošħ Williard I had indeed missed out the underscore and when working with it I had not noticed as I also do a text replace from . to _ and thought it was all correct. Even when debugging I did not see it, often we cannot see the obvious which is why a second opinion of those wiser than me is always good.

The working code is now as follows.

```
private void cmbobx_version_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Type t = this.GetType(); //need to get the type
    MethodInfo method = t.GetMethod("Getinfo_" + cmbobx_version.Text.Replace('.', '_'));   //put together function name
     method.Invoke(this, new object[] {Fridge, "Order" }); //call function with parameters
}
```

Please do be careful as the functions will have no references but it will compile and will work. It all works at run-time when you call the correct function.

Answer (score 0):

You should read about design patterns for example you could create polymorphic items that implement your function using for example the template design pattern. Try to avoid reflection as it is ‘slow’ and not type safe.